# How to get rows and columns count of a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

For an array in Java, we can get the `length` of the array with `array_name.length`. Similarly, how would one get the number of rows and columns of a **2D** array?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well you probably want `array_name.length` for getting the count of the rows and `array_name[0].length` for the columns. That is, if you defined your array like so:

```
T[][] array_name = new T[row][col];
array_name.length // row
array_name[0].length // col
```

Comment: Woow! that's great! Can you please tell me the logic of expression ((array_name[0].length)) that how this returns a number of columns?
I mean how is that expression returns a number of columns?
I want to learn its logic. thank you

Comment: @M.Barandov a 2d array is basically just an array of arrays. An example of this is if you have a 2d array with 5 rows and 4 columns, you can initialize it like this: T[][] array_name = new T[5][4]; While it looks like it makes a 2d array with 5 rows and 4 columns, it actually makes one 1d array with 5 elements. Each element is an inner array with 4 elements: *([array1,array2,array3,array4,array5] <= each array inside main array has 4 elements)*. Getting the length of any of these inner arrays will return the number of  "columns" in the 2d array.

Comment: @LadiOyeleye tnx a lot.